# How to prevent Google from showing sub domain name as title in search result?

Tags: google, search-engines, google-search, title, search-results

I don't want Google to show sub domain name (red circles in the below image) in search results. How to prevent Google from showing sub domain name as title in search result?

[image: sub domain name in search results]

Answer (score 1):

You don't have control over that. Google will modify the title of the search results as they see fit for the query.

Comment: Other similar sites that are not sub domain name in search result title!!!

Answer (score 1):

Google isn't showing the subdomain name. I think it's just coincidental that your subdomains are *similar* (but they are not *the same*). The text that appears in the title  in Google's search results will appear on your page, probably in the `title` element, or `Hn` elements, or even elsewhere on your page. (By the formation of the title, I'd guess the `title` element.)

Comment: i have not poetry or Qrosh in <Title> tag!!!!

Comment: Yes, you are right. I still can't believe it would be showing what appears to be the subdomain, without some other clues. "poetry" also appears in the meta description - in fact your meta description consists of only English words - maybe there is a connection? Whilst the meta description won't affect search engine ranking, it can affect the text which is shown in the serps.

Comment: i have not meta description on poems page!